# canonical link doesn't show on page-source react-helmet reactjs no ssr

Tags: reactjs, canonical-link, react-helmet

I'm having an issue on viewing canonical URL on page-source and here is the code in the web-app page

```
const Index = () => {
  const airportsQuery = useQuery(ALL_AIRPORTS_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      keyword: '',
    },
    skip: true,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: false,
  });

  let timer = null;
  function fetchOptions(inputValue, callback) {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      const response = airportsQuery.refetch({ keyword: inputValue });

      response.then(
        ({ data }) => callback(data?.allAirports || []),
        ({ message }) => {
          console.error('Server Error:', message);
        }
      );
    }, 100);
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Layout.Header />
      <Layout.Container width="full">
        <Helmet>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <title>eeeeee</title>
          <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.biletiniz.com/" />
        </Helmet>
        <HomePage
          fetchOptions={fetchOptions}
          onSubmit={variables =>
            Router.push(`/flight-offers?${qs.stringify(variables)}`)
          }
        />
      </Layout.Container>
      <Layout.Footer />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { default: lngDict = {} } = await import(
    `@biletiniz/intl/locales/tr.json`
  );
  return {
    props: { lng: 'tr', lngDict },
  };
}

export default withApollo({
  ssr: false,
})(Index);
```

when I inspect the page-source  I can't find the link or the title
How can I solve it?
And we don't have SSR how can I render the helmet on client-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React **renders** this using the **DOM**. The **DOM** is **changed via JavaScript** that is **sent with the HTML source code**. However, **JS can only change the DOM** (what the user can see), **not the source itself**. So you should inspect the DOM (F12 in all major browsers or right click and inspect) and not the page's source. **Modern crawlers** like the Google Crawler **inspect the DOM, not the source**, otherwise Single Page Applications like React couldn't understand its content because everything is rendered through JS. So you can totally leave your code as it is. Or change it in **React's static HTML file**.

Comment: thanks for your response but I add my website url to [link](https://freetools.seobility.net/en/seocheck/) and it returns that no canonical url is provided but I can see it in inspect the DOM

Comment: That's how I explained it. This SEO checker doesn't execute your JS as a search engine like Google does. This should not be a problem with popular search engines.

Comment: You can use this SEO checker for JS pages as well. Just select more options and choose crawling mode: Chrome (JavaScript enabled)
But you should also think about server side rendering for JS.